# How to keep terminal window open in AppleScript after end tell?

Tags: applescript, iterm

I have this osascript with a command

```
tell application "iTerm2"
  create window with default profile command "uwm"
end tell
```

Now the iTerm window closes at `end tell` but I want to keep iTerm window open to see my command result and work further. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the **iTerm2** window to stay *open* and *active* for further use, you cannot use `command` with `create window with default profile`.

You need to use the `write` *command* in proper context, e.g.:

```
tell application "iTerm2"
    create window with default profile
    tell current session of window 1 to write text "echo hello"
end tell
```

The above *example* **AppleScript** *code* used with `osascript`:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "iTerm2"' -e 'create window with default profile' -e 'tell current session of window 1 to write text "echo hello"' -e 'end tell'
```

- Replace `"echo hello"` in the *example* **AppleScript** *code* with your command, e.g.: `"uwm"`

Note: `osascript` can execute the *example* **AppleScript** *code* from a *file* using, e.g.:

```
osascript /path/to/filename.applescript
```

---

From the **iTerm2 AppleScript Dictionary**:

> **write** v : Send text as though it was typed.
>
> **write** specifier : The session to send to
>              [**contents of file** file] : Filename to send the contents of
>              [**text** text] : Text to send
>              [**newline** boolean] : If newline should be added to end of text (default: yes)

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any *error handling* and is meant only to show one of many ways accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.